# Alter property of Emberjs

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to EmberJs and I'm working on a project that I need to add properties in javascript and css in templantes generated by ember-cli, my difficulty is in finding the javascript and css files

```
When I search the project for the class or id, it shows me only what is in the dist that can not be changed

Can anyone with emberJS experience help me make these changes?






Template with i w[enter image description here][1]anna to work:

  <div class="top-banner">
    {{ top-banner pageBanner=model.news.banner }}
    {{ search-component exchangeTypes=model.exchangeType}}
  </div>

  {{bread-crumbs breadcrumbs=breadcrumbs}}

  <section class="container destaque noticia">
    {{title-content light=model.news.title}}
    <div class="row informacoes-news">
      <div class="col-xs-12 noticia-texto">
        {{{model.news.content}}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

    {{share-bar}}
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-12 download-container">
      <a class="teste" href="{{model.news.pdf}}">Download</a>
  </div>

  {{featured-news type="featured_news" noticias=model.featuredNews news=true}}

  {{contact-widget states=model.brazilState}}

  {{rodape-sitemap}}
```

Comment: So, you need to know where the .css files and templates and controllers are in the project structure? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline of the basics in an ember-twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/f537e51449c1c49ae32794b9d15bc6ff?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

It sounds like you inherited some code - and like you'd benefit from spending a few hours with the Ember guides tutorial: https://guides.emberjs.com/current

Happy travels!

application.hbs

```
<h1>{{appName}}</h1>

<h2>this is the application.hbs template (base template)</h2>

{{info-list}}
```

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'this is a property value seen in the application template...',
});
```

app.css

```
body {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

templates/components/info-list.hbs

```
<ul class='item-list'>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks so much , that help a lot !

Comment: ALSO, the component's .js and .hbs files work like the controller and template pair above. You can think about it as a 'scope' created by the module.